# How to clear all notification without clicking on notification in android

Tags: android, notifications

Plz don't mark this as duplicate.

I am working on notification and it is working fine. But what I want is that when notification appears, can we clear all the notification without clicking on the notification, means that suppose if I get 5 notification and when I simply open my app then that notification should have to removed without clicking on that notification.

Can we do this??

I have searched and all says to use setAutoCancel(true). I have already used this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to just clear `Notifications` according to id's do it this way,

while notifiy notification from `NotificationManager` set a tag to your nofification's and save id's of `notification's`  in a `Arraylist` like this

```
static ArrayList<String>notifIds=new ArrayList<>();

//your code


notificationManager.notify("myappnotif",NOTIFICATION_COUNT, builder.build());
        notifIds.add(data);
```

now to remove `Notifications` call `notificationManager.cancel(String tag, int id)` wherever you want like this

```
  NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)  getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    for(int i=0;i<MainActivity.notifIds.size();i++){
     notificationManager.cancel("myappnotif", i);
     }
```

and to remove all `Notification's` when application start's call `notificationManager.cancelAll();` in `onCreate` of `Launcher Activity`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     notificationManager.cancelAll();
  }
```

Comment: I don't want to click on notification, I just directly open my app, then automatically will have to clear all the notification of my app.

Comment: @DemoMail call `notificationManager.cancelAll();` in Oncreate method of Acivity, all notification will be cleared without click on a notification.

Comment: onStart would be better than onCreate

Comment: @KapilRajput & EugenPechanec  I will check both solutions and reply

Answer (score 11):

Use below code -

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancelAll();
```

Comment: where should i have to use this??

Comment: I am using NotificationCompat.Builder

Comment: @Demo Mail: You can use above code inside oncreate(). No issues in NotificationCompat.Builder.

Comment: I used Notification Listener to clear the notifications

Comment: @nmanikumar5:You can use NotificationManager to cancel notification of your app only. While NotificationListenerService can clear others apps notifications as well

Comment: @kevz Yeah, NotificationListenerService used